# Element only available after inspect element in selenium

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to get the contact names from [here](http://listings.fta-companies-au.com/l/101662595/BNP-Paribas-in-Sydney-NSW) and I'm facing a very strange problem. The content is visible in the browser but when I use selenium to find the element using xpath, I get no data. As soon as I click inspect element, selenium will find the data.

```
mydriver = webdriver.Chrome()
print 'Webdriver Started'
mydriver.get('http://listings.fta-companies-au.com/l/101662595/BNP-Paribas-in-Sydney-NSW')
contact_persons = mydriver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="data-block is-editable no-header"]//div[@class="srp-float-wrap flt-scroll-wrap"]//table[@class="srp-widget-table"]/tbody/tr')
for p in contact_persons:
    print p.text
```

When I just load and try find the data, it will return an empty list but as soon as I click inspect element, I'll get the required data.

I've also tried using requests and lxml to parse but and they too return empty data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the details table is only setup when you scroll to it. Try moving to the h2 tag with text -- Employees and Executives, using driver.moveto.... function. This should make the details available.

Comment: Worked wonders. If someone is wondering, I used this code
   
title = mydriver.find_element_by_xpath('//h2[contains(text(),"Employees")]')
   hover = ActionChains(mydriver).move_to_element(title)
   hover.perform()